# How can I iterate grepl over a vector of terms and a vector of text?

Tags: r

I have a vector of terms and some text

```
terms <- c("this","that","those")
text <- c("this is some text","here is more text with those words","more text than that other one","this ends it")
```

I would like to use grepl to search for all terms in all text and return the T/F by term of by text. I tried

```
sapply(text,grepl,pattern = terms)
```

but this only returned the answer for the first term

```
sapply(text,grepl,terms)
```

this worked but did not give the correct answers (every term returned as False (not appearing in any text).

```
sapply(text,grepl,sapply(terms,'['))
```

this also did not work and returned incorrect answers (all false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. When you `sapply`, the `pattern=` must be length 1, so you should add `x=text` in your `sapply`:

```r
out <- sapply(terms, grepl, x = text)
out
#       this  that those
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If you need to know if anything matches, you can use `rowSums` or `colSums`:

```r
colSums(out) > 0
#  this  that those 
#  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
setNames(rowSums(out) > 0, nm = text)
#                  this is some text here is more text with those words      more text than that other one 
#                               TRUE                               TRUE                               TRUE 
#                       this ends it 
#                               TRUE
```

(The `setNames` was purely to identify which logical is for which `text`, in case that's the direction you wanted to go.)

Answer (score 0):

### **Purrr with stringer or `grepl` alternative:**

If you have large character vectors, (i.e., `length(text)` is large), `stringr::str_detect` will be faster than `grepl`.

```r
terms <- c("this","that","those")
text <- c("this is some text","here is more text with those words","more text than that other one","this ends it")
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_df(set_names(terms,terms), ~str_detect(text, .x))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   this  that  those
#>   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#> 2 FALSE FALSE TRUE 
#> 3 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
map_df(set_names(terms,terms), grepl, text)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   this  that  those
#>   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#> 2 FALSE FALSE TRUE 
#> 3 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>